# Поворот объекта за мышкой в X и Z в 3д игре

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Может кто подсказать как в 3д организовать слежение объекта за курсором? Трабл в том, что мышь в 3д, поэтому объект вращается по 3осям. А у меня вид сверху, то есть поворачиваться должен объект только в X и Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у тебя вид сверху, а значит камера является Ортографической, то у тебя никак не может поворачиваться объект в сторону Z. Он должен поворачиваться **вокруг** оси Z. Разве что ты чего-то не менял.

В целом один из вариантов скрипта может выглядеть так:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseFollow2D : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 mousePosition;
    public float moveSpeed = 2f;

    void Update () {
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);    
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Тот самый поворот
        // вычисляем разницу между текущим положением и положением мыши
        Vector3 difference = mousePosition - transform.position; 
        difference.Normalize();
        // вычисляемый необходимый угол поворота
        float rotation_z = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        // Применяем поворот вокруг оси Z
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation_z);    
    }
}
```

Если создать сцену 2D игры, расположить на ней просто куб и накинуть скрипт, то куб будет двигаться и поворачиваться в сторону мыши.

В целом тут использован **[Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)**, который преобразует position (позицию) из экранного пространства в мировое пространство.

---

Если нужно вращение по другой оси - просто поменяй в коде

Comment: Я решил это так:
`void LookOnCursor(){
  //заставляет персонажа следить за курсором мышки
  Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
  Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
  float hitdist = 0;

  if (playerPlane.Raycast (ray, out hitdist)) {
   Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint (hitdist);

   Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (targetPoint - transform.position);

   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRotation, lookspeed * Time.deltaTime);
  }
 }`

Comment: @erpuer да, тоже вариант.